# Display dictionary objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4.3

I want to display every object alone, for this dictionary (email,city,name) only:
{"contact_search":{"0":{"email":"xxx","city":"xxx","name":"xxx"}}}

Comment: `NSString *email = [NSString stringWithString:[yourDict objectForKey:@"email"]];`  ?? please clarify your question

Comment: What have you tried and what's the difference between that and what you want?

Comment: how u created your dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you actually want.

```
NSDictionary *contactSearch = [dictionary objectForKey:@"contact_search"];

[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, NSDictionary *contact, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *name  = [contact objectForKey:@"name"]; 
    NSString *city  = [contact objectForKey:@"city"];
    NSString *email = [contact objectForKey:@"email"];

    NSLog(@"name: %@, city: %@, email: %@", name, city, email);
}];
```

This will grab the dictionary of objects and then cycle through each key/value pair printing the values

Comment: iam not able to reach the values of email,city,name. So what I want is to grab the values of these objects.